# CREATE TABLE in AWS Athena with an Anonymous JSON Array

Tags: arrays, json, amazon-athena, presto

I am working in AWS Athena.  I am trying to CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE that has an anonymous JSON array in it.  For example:

```
[{"key1":"value1a","key2":"value2a",...},{"key1":"value1b","key2":"value2b",...}]
```

I cannot get the table definition to correctly parse the array of objects into a set of rows.
I have tried this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testdata.trynum85 (
  data struct<`key1`:string,
              `key2`:string>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1',
  'strip.outer.array'='true'
) LOCATION 's3://mys3/new-json-structure/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

and

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testdata.trynum85 (
  data array<struct<`key1`:string,
                    `key2`:string>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1',
  'strip.outer.array'='false'
) LOCATION 's3://mys3/new-json-structure/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

and with both cases, when I query, the logic only finds the first object in the array.

```
SELECT stuff.key1
FROM "testdata"."trynum85 ", UNNEST(data) AS t(stuff)
returns
key1
----
value1a
```

value1b never appears.

If I modify the data and make the array named, i.e.

```
{"iamme":[{"key1":"value1a","key2":"value2a",...},{"key1":"value1b","key2":"value2b",...}]}
```

Then queries can yield the list of results on a query for key1.

How do I handle the anonymous array?

Comment: What happens if you just do `SELECT * FROM trynum85` in the second case (when the column type is an array)? Do you see the full array (as a single row)?